# Fluent scroll in ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox

Is it possible to have a fluent scroll in ListBox? I mean, so you can also scroll through item content, not through items as whole.

```
<ListBox Height="59" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Grid.Row="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```

As you can see on the picture, first item is far too large, but I still can't scroll through its content.

[image: illustration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` to enable scrolling by pixels.  Setting it to `True` (the default) enables scrolling by *whole items*, so scrolling down by a single "line" will attempt to bring the *entire next item* into view.  That can cause you to jump past parts of the current item if it doesn't fit entirely within the viewport, which sounds exactly like what is happening.

Comment: I thought that CanContentScroll was False by default. Thank you very much!